# What is the input value of this OJ on leetcode(Binary Tree Level Order Traversal )?

Tags: python, tree

It's a question from leetcode as linked here.
https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-level-order-traversal/

So here is my code, but I really don't know what the input is and its relationship to TreeNode defined below.

> ## Definition for a binary tree node.
>
> ```
> # class TreeNode:
> #     def __init__(self, x):
> #         self.val = x
> #         self.left = None
> #         self.right = None
> ```

```
class Solution:
    # @param {TreeNode} root
    # @return {integer[][]}
    def levelOrder(self, root):
        if not root:
            return []
        else:
            printout, CurrLevel = [], [root]
            while CurrLevel:
                printout.extend(CurrLevel)
                NextLevel = []
                for item in CurrLevel:
                    temp = []
                    if item.left != None:
                        temp.append(item.left)
                    if item.right != None:
                        temp.append(item.right)
                    NextLevel = NextLevel.extend(temp)
                CurrLevel = NextLevel
            return printout
```

> Input:    [1,2]
>
> Output:   [[1,2]]
>
> Expected: [[1],[2]]

So I met this finally, so what's the treenode anyway? Why does it appear like a list?
Well this is a OJ problem and I am just so unsure about the testing case, as I can't understand how the treenode presented here. As described in the problem, it seems there is only one "root" element is input each time.

I am confused because it seems that for each test case (each problem in leetcode contains tens or hundreds of test cases to test the validity of the program), only one TreeNode (named root) is inputted, if so, I could happily reference its .val, its .left or its .right, therefore a tree could be traversed up to down from the "root" element. BUT through the test case I see here (once the wrong solution is produced by the program, it produced a report, that's why I show the "input" [1, 2] presented here), I see a list, or at least list alike, which contains two elements. What I expected is only one TreeNode called root inputted here, but now I see a list. Clearly I know I am supposed to printout a list of lists, which differs to the confusion I raised up here. 
So in [1, 2], I can't understand what 1 and 2 represent respectively, an integer? A treenode? **Actually I think [1, 2] itself is a treenode where 1 and 2 stands for its .val, .left.**

Importantly, my code is based on the assumption that each input is one node, and leave the [1,2,3](may stands for .val, .left, .right of the TreeNode) whatever input behind. I later found I did do something wrong and revised my code as follows:

```
class Solution:
    # @param {TreeNode} root
    # @return {integer[][]}
    def levelOrder(self, root):
        if not root:
            return []
        else:
            printout, CurrLevel = [], [root]
            while CurrLevel:
                values = []
                for node in CurrLevel:
                    values = values.append(node.val)
                printout.append(values)
                NextLevel = []
                for item in CurrLevel:
                    temp = []
                    if item.left != None:
                        temp.append(item.left)
                    if item.right != None:
                        temp.append(item.right)
                    NextLevel = NextLevel.extend(temp)
                CurrLevel = NextLevel
            return printout
```

This time it seems the following bug occurs:

> Input:    [1]
>
> Output:   [null]
>
> Expected: [[1]]

Well I have checked my code, and found that node.val produces 1 when Input:[1], while values produces [null]! That's so weird!

Comment: Please fix your formatting to [PEP8 standards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and clarify your question. Your question makes zero sense to me as written: "what is the input value" then at the end: "Input: [1, 2]". What are you asking really?

Comment: Additionally, prefer "is None" to "== None" tests. "== None" probably isn't doing what you think.

Comment: Thank you. I have revised the question.

Comment: Not enough, I'm afraid. Example questions I have reading over this: What's OJ? "What's the treenode anyway?" -- what are you referring to as "the treenode"? That only appears in your code in comments, so you tell us!

Comment: I am really sorry I forget the important things, well now I have supplemented the link to the Leetcode Online Judgement page and emphasize out the definition of TreeNode.

Comment: I think you're just confused because you're self-taught and you haven't had a formal introduction to trees. Specifically, it seems like you're tripping up on class names using somewhat technical terms referring to parts of trees. The list presentation is a list of lists, where each inner list is all the nodes (elements, the numbers in this case) on one level. The levels are the ones on the same horizontal alignment the way they draw the trees -- it's their distance from the "root" (the single element at the top the way they draw it, but it could also be at the bottom).

Comment: So TreeNode is just a class describing one individual node, storing the info it needs to understand its position in the tree -- what's on its left? what's on its right? (Remember we always traverse the tree from the root, so that's what's coming up as you descend the tree looking at their pictures.) It's only left and right because it's a _binary_ tree. Every element can have at most two things below it.

Comment: Hi, I have supplement my question, which is a little verbose and I hope you can read it. The new edited version refers to another confusion of mine. Thanks for your patience toward a newbie coder.

Comment: According to the example, [1, 2] is not even a valid representation of a tree. If the tree had a root of 1 and that was the only data in it, the representation would be [[1]]. That's a list containing a list containing 1. The outer list is the tree itself. The inner list is "level 0" containing only the root. Adding 2 as the root's `.right` would produce [[1], [2]]. Adding 3 as the root's `.left` would produce [[1], [3, 2]]. The numbers are the values of the node, each inner list is a level, where `inner_list[0]` == `.left` and `inner_list[1]` == `.right`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think since a tree can't be represented anyway, the leecode website just compromise on this and make it a list which stands for the three attributes of the TreeNode. I don't know if I am thinking right but I do know why I produced a wrong result in the first program. Now could you help me checking my new version of code? I really find the Output: [null] a weird one.